# how to test an ejb in a client application using was7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I´ve my ejb, with it´s client packed in an ear which it´s deployed on a was7
Now I need to test it with junit so I created a standalone java application I added the jar generated by the ejb client and try calling it before making the actual test cases:

```
    @EJB private static ConfiguratorIDA conf;
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        conf.setupIsbanDataAccess();
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My was is running as well as my ejb but when a I run my application I get NullPointerException on conf.setupIsbanDataAccess();

Does anyone knows how to call an ejb in an standalone java app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Injection (including `@EJB`) only works if you're using the [application client container](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rcli_javacmd.html), because the container needs to have an opportunity to perform the injection before running your main method.  If you really want to use a standalone JVM, then you'll need to include the [EJB thinclient](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html) in your classpath and manually lookup the EJB using JNDI rather than trying to use injection.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented unit tests on EJB3 modules with the help of [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).  There is a nice and concise blog article on how to do it [here](http://sachinparnami.blogspot.de/2009/09/devlopement-testing-using-jpa-junit.html).

Comment: isn´t that library justo for handling connections??

Comment: Yes and no. Put simply, it lets you run the unit tests against your EJBs and an in-memory database without having to deploy to an application server.